# Pandas Create Link Pairs from Multiple Rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sankey-diagram

I have a df with `id` as the flow id, `dttm` as the `step` modification time, and `step` as the steps in the flow. It is currently ordered by `dttm`. There could be any number of steps for a particular `id`.

Current df:

```
    id      dttm                  step
0   81      2015-05-26 07:56:03   A
1   81      2015-05-26 08:19:07   B
2   81      2015-05-26 08:32:05   C
3   91      2015-05-26 08:07:12   B
4   91      2015-05-26 08:07:12   C
```

I want to create link data to feed into a Sankey. Therefore I ultimately want a df with three columns: `source`, `target`, and `value`. `value` is the count of `id`s that have such a step pair.

Desired df:

```
    source   target   value
0   A        B        1
1   B        C        2
```

I know I can stuff `step` into one row with either `groupby` or possibly `cat`. However, I think that would just create a different starting point without actually advancing a solution. Part of what makes it tough is that the steps depend on `dttm` to stay ordered so that the steps are appropriately paired. Also, the fact that it has to be dynamic because there could be any number of steps adds to the difficulty.

How should I dynamically "stuff"  the `step` column to arrive at the link data?

Is there a way to join the df to itself to get all of the pairs, and then remove rows that are created during the join but are nonsense?

Thank you for any and all insight!

Comment: What is the column `target`? And why would it need to be dynamic if you just use a groupby.

Comment: `target` is the next step in the flow. and because `groupby` will put all the steps into one line (i.e. A --> B --> C) rather than unique pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a solution. It is not a one step solution like Scott's, but I think it's a little simpler to understand. also, it runs much, much faster:

Add a sequence to each group of `id`. then duplicate the df to allow a self-merge:

```
df['sequence'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount()
df2 = df
```

Merge the dataframes on `id`, then only keep the rows that make sense based on the sequence:

```
result = df.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
result = result[result['sequence_x']+1==result['sequence_y']]
```

Group the resulting df by step pairs and use `size` to get `value`. Then reset the index and rename the columns:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(result.groupby(['step_x','step_y']).size().rename('value'))
result = result.reset_index()
result.columns = ['source','target','value']
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
(df.groupby('id')['step'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, x[1:]))).set_index([0,1]).assign(count=1))
   .rename_axis(['id','source','target'])
   .sum(level=[1,2]).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  source target  count
0      A      B      1
1      B      C      2
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, this works perfectly! Please check out my alternate solution also. I like the condensed nature of your solution, but it takes significantly longer to run.

Comment: @CameronTaylor I am glad you got what you needed.  +1 from me on your solution.